# Unable to send push notification using FCM Http V1 with "apns-push-type" set to "liveactivity"

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are migrating from legacy FCM API to FCM Http V1 and I am using a PHP third party package ([Kreait](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php)) trying to send a push notification using [FCM HTTP V1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1), with apns config as follow (setting "liveactivity" as "apns-push-type"):

```
Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage::__set_state(array(
   'target' => 
  Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\MessageTarget::__set_state(array(
     'type' => 'token',
     'value' => 'the device token',
  )),
   'data' => 
  Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\MessageData::__set_state(array(
     'data' => 
    array (
    ),
  )),
   'notification' => 
  Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification::__set_state(array(
     'title' => 'test',
     'body' => 'Hello World!',
     'imageUrl' => NULL,
     'clickAction' => NULL,
     'icon' => NULL,
     'color' => NULL,
     'sound' => NULL,
  )),
   'androidConfig' => 
  Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\AndroidConfig::__set_state(array(
     'config' => 
    array (
      'ttl' => '3600s',
      'priority' => 'normal',
      'notification' => 
      array (
        'title' => 'test',
        'body' => 'Hello World!',
        'click_action' => 'action1',
        'icon' => 'notification_icon_resource_name',
        'color' => '#ffffff',
        'sound' => 'default',
      ),
    ),
  )),
   'apnsConfig' => 
  Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\ApnsConfig::__set_state(array(
     'config' => 
    array (
      'headers' => 
      array (
        'apns-push-type' => 'liveactivity',
        'apns-topic' => 'com.myapp.domain.push-type.liveactivity',
      ),
      'payload' => 
      array (
        'aps' => 
        array (
          'content-available' => 1,
          'content-state' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )),
   'webPushConfig' => NULL,
   'fcmOptions' => NULL,
))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Invalid [apns-push-type] set for apns platform
```

All values for "apns-push-type" listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending-notification-requests-to-apns) are working fine but "liveactivity" and "pushtotalk" are not.

Does [FCM V1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) dropped the support for "liveactivity" and "pushtotalk"  as "apns-push-type" ? Or am I doing something wrong?